# How can i control spread of instances on Y axis like that? Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I currently have a grid of point clouds (white dots) and I am trying to distribute an instance of an orange line from -Y to +Y over each point. As you can see in this gif, I have been able to achieve this to some extent. However, my next goal is to distribute these lines in a pyramid shape while maintaining the quantization steps and spacing between the dots. (I am a newbie here and hope you can help me)

[image]

[image]

My node tree:

[image]

Blend file:
https://blendswap.com/blend/30976

Comment: Your node tree is too small to read. Maybe upload your blend?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to trust a google drive link. I think blendswap.com is where people want blend files posted.
You should edit your question with the infos.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about that! I updated my question with new link
@HaskellMcRavin

Comment: Like that? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Apb9O6AX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Apb9O6AX/)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Not exactly, but at least now I can understand the principle of action! I needed one large pyramid, and I still can't achieve it in the same way as in shader nodes. But overall thanks again @ugorek

Comment: Your piramid: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3e8zgkdss6  
Just implement this function with math nodes.